# Simple regular expression to determine login and password from a line

Tags: regex, expression

I need your help with creating a regular expression for this:

(URL;login;;password)
`http://www.random-site.com;daba1169;;582485
http://www.random-site2.com;daba1534;;256485`
etc.

Lets say i need a regular expression to get my login and password to the first site.
Login is easy:
(?<=http://www.random-site.com.com;).*(?=;;)

But I cant make a regular expression for the password (to get the number 582485), could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Just split it by `;` and get the right elements...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just split/explode on `;` and get the relevant pieces?

If you insist on a regex, just use this:

```
/;(.*?);;(.*)/
```

The first subpattern will be the username, the second subpattern will be the password.